# Can not perform swipe-to-delete on UITableView if it is in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have created a UITableView that can perform swipe-to-delete on its table cells in normal cases, but when I put the UITableView into a UIScrollView that can be horizontally scrollable, the outer scrollview will swallow the swipe event, thus the swipe-to-delete is not workable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell you that you have to give up one for your function since the two functions rely on the same gesture.
If you want to keep the swipe-delete, set the outer `scrollview.scrollEnabled = NO`. I think that would help.

If not, have a button to start the tableview edit mode. That will make you delete cell with the scrollview can be slided.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found solution!

Subclass the outer UIScrollView, and override a method

> -(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer

```
@interface AllowSwipeScrollView : UIScrollView

@end

@implementation AllowSwipeScrollView

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    BOOL inTableViewCell = .... // check the current touch is in table view cell

    if (inTableViewCell) {
        return NO;
    }else{
        return [super gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:gestureRecognizer];
    }
}

@end
```

And make sure the UITableView instances are in AllowSwipeScrollView.

Comment: @Yoko if this method returns NO, the inner UITableView would receive swipe event automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try   This  condition

if (ScrollView == self.tableView) return;

in   scrollviewdidscroll   method.